# I can't connect to mongodb database as it is showing errors in the debug console using node.js

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I am making login form in which i want to connect my mongodb database but everytime I run and debug the code its showing error in connecting to database

this is the error that is coming

```
error in connecting database
index.js:30
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught MongooseServerSelectionError MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (c:\Users\Viraj Bhatia\Desktop\login-form html\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at openUri (c:\Users\Viraj Bhatia\Desktop\login-form html\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers:533:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers:507:7)
```

using this code

```
// first import install libery 

var express = require("express");
var bodyParse = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const e = require("express");

//create app

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParse.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

// conect database


mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/mydb', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

var db = mongoose.connection;

// check connect

db.on('error', () => console.log("error in connecting database"));
db.once('open', () => console.log("Connected to Database"));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    res.set({
        "Allow-access-Allow-Origin": '*'
    })

    return res.redirect('index.html');

}).listen(3000);



app.post("/login", async (request, response) => {
    try {
        //adding
        const username = request.body.username;
        const password = request.body.password;

        const usermail = db.collection('users').findOne({ email: username }, (err, res) => {
            if (res == null) {
                response.send("Invalid information!❌❌❌! Please create account first");
            }
            else if (err) throw err;


            if (res.password === password) {
                return response.redirect('login.html');
            }
            else {
                response.send("Invalid Password!❌❌❌");
            }


        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        response.send("Invalid information❌");
    }

})
```

I am expecting that it does not say error in connecting to database instead it should say connected to database

Comment: while `0.0.0.0` is a valid LISTEN address, `0.0.0.0` is NOT a valid IP address to connect TO - you need the actual IP address where your mongo is running (note: if it's on the local host, same as this code, you could use `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: You should better print the real error message instead of static `"error in connecting database"` which does not give any information.

Comment: i made it work!